# If $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space , then for any subset $S$ of $X$ ,$(S, \tau')$ will be a subspace.

Tags: general-topology

If $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space , then for any subset $S$ of $X$ ,$(S, \tau')$  a subspace.where $\tau'$ = [$U \cap S$ : $U$ is an open set in $X$] .

Is the statement true?

I think the statement is true.

If not, can anyone please explain me with counter example why it is not true?

Comment: Why do you think that it is true?

Comment: The first condition for a topology is to be a subset of subsets. If $\tau$ is a topology of $X$, then $X\in\tau$. It $\tau$ were also a topology of $S\subset X$, then $X\in\tau$ must be a subset of $S$. Therefore, $X=S$ is the only case in which $(S,\tau)$ will also be a topological space.

Comment: The topology of a subspace is [an entirely new topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology#Definition) created out of $\tau$ and $S$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\tau$ is a collection of subsets of $X.$ In particular, $X$ is in $\tau.$ Thus, if $S$ does not equal $X,$ then there is an element of $\tau$ (namely $X$) that is not a subset of $S.$ Thus, $\tau$ cannot be a topology on $S.$

EDIT: Your new statement is correct. If $S$ is a subset of a topological space $(X, \tau),$ then the subspace topology on $S$ is DEFINED by
$$\tau'=\{U \cap S \mid U \in \tau\}.$$
Thus, your statement is true by definition of the subspace topology.

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please give it a read?@Pawel